# How to "fill in" subplots one by one using a for loop?

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I'm currently trying to make subplots and then fill them in using a loop. More specifically, I have around 50 CSV files that each have two columns. I want to create a scatter plot using the two columns for each file, thus resulting in 50 plots. The code that I have is:

```
files = os.listdir() # List to contain the 50 file names.

fig, axes = plt.subplots(nrows=10, ncols=5, figsize=(45, 30))

axes = axes.ravel()

for idx, filename in enumerate(range(1, len(files) + 1)):
    df = pd.read_csv(files[idx - 1]) # Read in the appropriate file.
    axes[idx] = sns.scatterplot(x='pred', y='obs', data=df, alpha=0.3)
    axes[idx].set_title('Plot {}'.format(idx), fontsize='x-large')
```

If I run this code, I get 49 empty subplots and all of the data is overlapped into the last subplot. How would I achieve what I want? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass the axes as a parameter to `scatterplot`

```
sns.scatterplot(x='pred', y='obs', data=df, alpha=0.3, ax=axes[idx])
```